# Como usar un Input type="week" que comience en día domingo?

Tags: html5

He querido utilizar este tipo de valor en html5, pero en los calendarios comienzan el día lunes y terminan domingo y quiero que sea de domingo a sabado, como es podría hacer?

Comment: Sube el codigo que has intentado

Comment: Esta etiqueta input type="week" no tiene forma de configurar el dia que comienza la semana, solo ha quedado para usar el formato calendario americano (international ISO 8601) Ya esa pregunta se la han planteado la gente de **stackoverflow USA** y no han podido resolverla y que no hay soporte de atributos como por el DOM [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220056/how-to-make-html5-week-input-type-start-on-sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220056/how-to-make-html5-week-input-type-start-on-sunday) [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week](https://develo

Comment: Más allá de un posible uso, el problema con que te vas a enfrentar usando ese tipo de input, es de [compatibilidad con los navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_input_input-week). Ante ese tipo de situación, concuerdo con la respuesta más abajo que da @AlexanderRodriguez, es mucho más conveniente que uses herramientas como Datepicker, donde en las opciones se puede establecer el día inicial.